# 'google/protobuf/stubs/common.h' file not found

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, protocol-buffers

I installed firebase using cocoa pods but now my project cannot find the file `'google/protobuf/stubs/common/h'` after trying to import the file using `#include <google/protobuf/stubs/common.h>` 
any help is appreciated.

I've tried deleting derived data, pod update, but neither have worked. It is finding `google/protobuf/stubs/common.h` in another file so I'm not sure why it's not finding it in this one.

Answer (score 0):

Did you open your .xcworkspace instead of ..xcodeproj after install ?

Comment: yeah it's the only file i open

Comment: I would close the project, do a 'pod update' and restart

Comment: yeah that didnt help much either